# Trying to make buttons active in Tiptap Vue

Tags: vue.js, tiptap

I'm trying to create buttons for the menu bar on my rich text editor being built with Tiptap Vue 3. I'm having a hard time with the `isActive()` method because I'm getting an error with the Promise under it, to be more specific: `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'isActive')`

Here is the code for `MenuItem.vue`:

```
<template>
  <button
    class="menu-item"
    :class="{ 'is-active bg-zinc-800 rounded-sm': isActive(editor) }"
    @click="(e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      action();
    }"
    :title="title"
  >
    <i :class="`ri-${icon} ri-fw`"></i>
  </button>
</template>

<script>
import 'remixicon/fonts/remixicon.css';
export default {
  props: {
    icon: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    title: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    action: {
      type: Function,
      required: true,
    },
    editor: {
      type: Object,
      required: true,
    }
  },
  methods: {
    async isActive(editor){
      return await editor.isActive('bold')
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

`MenuBar.vue`:

```
<template>
  <div class="text-xl">
    <template v-for="(item, index) in items">
      <span
          class="divider"
          v-if="item.type === 'divider'"
          :key="`divider${index}`"
      >
        |
      </span>
      <menu-item class="p-1" :editor="editor" v-else :key="index" v-bind="item"/>
    </template>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import MenuItem from "@/components/new_text_editor/MenuItem.vue";

export default {
  components: {
    MenuItem,
  },
  props: {
    editor: {
      type: Object,
      required: true
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      items: [
        {
          icon: "bold",
          title: "Bold",
          action: () => this.editor.chain().focus().toggleBold().run(),
        },
        {
          icon: "italic",
          title: "Italic",
          action: () => this.editor.chain().focus().toggleItalic().run(),
        },
      ]
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

`Editor.vue`:

```
<template>
  <menu-bar :editor="editor"></menu-bar>
  <editor-content class="border rounded-md" :editor="editor" />
</template>

<script setup>
import {EditorContent, useEditor} from '@tiptap/vue-3'
import StarterKit from '@tiptap/starter-kit'
import TableHeader from "@tiptap/extension-table-header";
import Link from "@tiptap/extension-link";
import MenuBar from "@/components/new_text_editor/MenuBar.vue";
import BulletList from "@tiptap/extension-bullet-list";
import Bold from "@tiptap/extension-bold";

const CustomBulletList = BulletList.extend({
  addCommands() {
    return {
      ...this.parent?.(),
      toggleBulletClass: (className) => ({ commands }) => {
        return commands.updateAttributes("bulletList", { class: className });
      },
    };
  },
});

const CustomTableHeader = TableHeader.extend({
  addAttributes() {
    return {
      ...this.parent?.(),
      colwidth: {
        default: null,
        parseHTML: (element) => {
          const colwidth = element.getAttribute("colwidth");
          return colwidth ? [parseInt(colwidth, 10)] : null;
        },
        renderHTML: (attributes) => {
          return {
            colwidth: attributes.colwidth,
            style: attributes.colwidth
              ? `width: ${attributes.colwidth}px`
              : null,
          };
        },
      },
    };
  },
});

const CustomLink = Link.extend({
  addAttributes() {
    return {
      ...this.parent?.(),
      rel: {
        default: null,
      },
    };
  },
});

const editor = useEditor({
  content: '',
  extensions: [
    StarterKit,
    CustomBulletList,
    CustomTableHeader,
    CustomLink,
    Bold,
  ],
  editorProps: {
    attributes: {
      class: 'prose dark:prose-invert prose-sm sm:prose-base lg:prose-lg xl:prose-2xl m-5 focus:outline-none'
    }
  }
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You cannot use an async method in this case (or at least, you cannot use the promise returned from it). Your `isActive` method should be synchronous.

```
methods: {
  isActive(){
    return this.editor.isActive(this.title.toLowerCase())
  }
}
```

Also, you can call the editor directly in template:

```
  <button
    class="menu-item"
    :class="{ 'is-active bg-zinc-800 rounded-sm': editor.isActive(title.toLowerCase()) }"
    @click="(e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      action();
    }"
    :title="title"
  >
    <i :class="`ri-${icon} ri-fw`"></i>
  </button>
```

2. The error is stating that the editor is undefined. You have two options:

Make sure the editor is initiated before mounting the menu-bar.

```
<menu-bar v-if="editor" :editor="editor"></menu-bar>
```

Or, check if the editor is defined before calling it.

```
isActive() {
  return !!this.editor && this.editor.isActive(this.title.toLowerCase());
}
```

Working [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/vigilant-wave-jzvdsw?file=%2Fsrc%2FMenuItem.vue%3A29%2C22).

Comment: I cannot access the sandbox.

Comment: @codewriter3000 ah, you're right. I forgot to make it public. thanks for letting me know. fixed it